# Detect if enemy is facing Player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, distance

I am making a game in which if the distance is less than 2 and the enemy is facing the player, text comes up with a restart option. In the update there is an if and else statement which should detect if the enemy is behind or in front of the player. However, the in front option seems to be called once the distance is less than 2, regardless of if the player is facing the npc.

This script is attached to the Enemy:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyFollow : MonoBehaviour {

Transform player; 
Transform enemy; 
public GameObject EnemyCaughtCam;
public Text SheCaughtYou;
public GameObject Restart;

public float Speed = 3f;
public float rotS = 3f;
public float sT = 3f;
NavMeshAgent nav;
float timeTillOptionsMenu = 3.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake() {
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MainCamera").transform;
    //enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Enemy").transform;
    nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
    EnemyCaughtCam.SetActive(false);
    SheCaughtYou.text = "";
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    nav.SetDestination (player.position);
    DistanceDeath();

    if (npcIsFacingPlayer (player)&& !playerIsFacingNpc(player))
        print ("Behind");
    else if (npcIsFacingPlayer (player)&& playerIsFacingNpc(player))
        print ("In Front");
        DistanceDeath ();
}

public void DistanceDeath(){

    float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, 
        transform.position);              


    if (distance < 2 ){

        EnemyCaughtCam.SetActive(true);
        SheCaughtYou.text = "SHE CAUGHT YOU!";

        timeTillOptionsMenu -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(timeTillOptionsMenu < 0)
        {
            Restart.SetActive(true);

        }


    }

}

public bool npcIsFacingPlayer(Transform other)
{
    Vector3 toOther =
    other.position - transform.position;
    return (Vector3.Dot(toOther, transform.forward) > 0);
}
public bool playerIsFacingNpc(Transform other)
{
    Vector3 toOther =
    transform.position - other.position;
    return (Vector3.Dot(toOther, other.forward) > 0);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are missing some brackets, second there is an stra `DistanceDeath`call, here is how your function `Update` is read:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    nav.SetDestination (player.position);

    /** what does the call do here? */
    DistanceDeath(); 

    if (npcIsFacingPlayer (player)&& !playerIsFacingNpc(player))
        print ("Behind");
    else if (npcIsFacingPlayer (player)&& playerIsFacingNpc(player))
        print ("In Front");

    /** are you missing brackets here? Distance Death is always called */
    DistanceDeath (); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately when i added them it still calls the distance death function, i think it may be something to do with the logic of the statements themselves but cannot figure it out

Comment: @Cdalyz, well there is another `DistanceDeath` I just saw, second line

Comment: This worked, removed the second DistanceDeath() , thanks a million